# Child controls in asp.net Blazor not refreshing. StateHasChanged() not working

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Please refer to the following https://github.com/CD1010/BlazorWizard.git for this question. The sample is in **StepActivations Branch**

I have a page called DemoWizard, which incorporates a 3 step wizard. When i click the "Toggle Enabled" button, the second and third steps links should go to enabled or disabled state.  It seems however, that the first time takes 2 clicks to turn off the headers, and the state is always behind.
So it appears that StateHasChanged() is not refreshing child states properly.
Note that the refresh() method was an attempt to get at least step2 to refresh properly, but to no avail.

Any idea why?
the click handler that does toggle is below.

```
void OnClick()
{
    step2Enabled = !step2Enabled;
    step3Enabled = !step3Enabled;



    StateHasChanged();
    Step2.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't showing up exactly as advertised, but i **think** what you need to do is add an event callback to the Blazorize CheckEdit component:

```cs
<Blazorize.CheckEdit @bind-Checked="@Parent.IsValid" CheckedChanged="@VerifyEnabledTabs">Check Me</Blazorise.CheckEdit>
```

where `VerifyEnabledTabs` is a method on the top level `Wizard` that can assess where you are and what is complete / filled / checked / whatever, to allow certain links to be active.